# What Buddha taught by his knowledge about human life?

Tags: philosophy

Buddha taught that everything is ephemeral and everything is grief. What a seeker should do in the above circumstances?

Answer (score 2):

Buddha taught all worldly things are ephemeral but did not teach everything is "grief". "Grief" is an emotion created by the mind rather than a characteristic of things.

The seeker keeps reflecting & examining how all worldly things are ephemeral until the mind realises completely that ephemeral things cannot be any other way or '*suchness*' ('[*tathātā*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tath%C4%81t%C4%81)').

This will result in the mind giving up desires & expectations towards ephemeral things.

This is described at the end of the [Anatta-Lakkhana Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.059.mend.html), as follows:

> *O monks, the well-instructed noble disciple, seeing thus, gets wearied of form, gets wearied of feeling, gets wearied of perception,
>   gets wearied of mental formations, gets wearied of consciousness.
>   Being wearied he becomes passion-free. In his freedom from passion, he
>   is emancipated.*

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate (let go of) attachment, aversion, and ignorance towards all Sankhara.

Comment: It might be more helpful if another word was used in the place of sankhara, such as 'things'.